# How to replace string with tags used

Tags: php, regex, string

I want to replace the string `"<Reason/>"` with empty space or just nothing.

I tried `str_replace('<Reason/>','',$string)` but it won't take the tags. 
I tried `str_preg('<Reason/>','', $string)` but it leaves the the tags `"<>"`.
I tried `str_preg('/^<Reason/>/','', $string)` but its gives me exception with unknown modifier `'>'`.

What can I do to remove the whole string along with tags `"<Reason/>"`?

Comment: Have you tried escaping the <>, i.e. str_replace('\<Reason/\>','',$string), also if you are enclosing with "/" you need to escape the enclosed "/", i.e. str_replace('/^\<Reason\/\>/','',$string);

Comment: Yeah, like most regex engines, replacement isn't done in place. It's actually a temporary that is built up internally via appending non-match parts of the string with matched replacement. When it's done, the temporary is copied to the LHS via the assignment operator.

Answer (score 2):

You probably forgot to assign the result back to the original variable.

The following code works:

```
$string = str_replace('<Reason/>','',$string);
```

**Full example:**

```
$string = '<Reason/>lalala<Reason/>';
$string = str_replace('<Reason/>','',$string);
echo $string;
```

**Output**

```
lalala
```

Answer (score 1):

for Case Insensitive, use

> str_ireplace()

instead of `

> str_replace()

`